How to check memory footprint of BACnet Stack on Windows and Linux Platform
How much memory footprint of the BACnet Stack uses. Here, Client expects detailed memory footprint report so that he can quickly decide whether the stack is feasible or not for their memory requirement.
Can anyone help me on this
Do u know any third party tool which can perform me this memory related test

You need to give a sense of which O/S or platform; e.g. Windows or Linux, or embedded (?).  And the stack might just have a provision to give a better/more precise snapshot.
